DFX conversion into DST file format for Embroidery Purpose
Apparently people who use embroidery machines require a dst file format, I went to have a hat embroidered with a design I made in aspire, I saved it as a dfx and a ai (for photoshop), I figured they'd be able to use one of those. Nope, I went to 3 different online converters and all needed dst and couldn't even open a dfx. So my question is, anyone know if it is possible to convert a dfx to a dst ? Not looking too promising, saw some file conversion websites, no luck with those. hard to believe these people limit themselves to a single obscure file extension.
